# BPS 3.5.0 and Activiti

Tags: wso2, activiti, wso2-business-process

I'm new with WSO2 BPS and I was wondering if, given a process definition (created using Eclipse Activiti plugin), it is possible to restrict the instantiation of that process to a specific role or user. That's to say, if I have **user_1** with role **role_1** and a **user_2** with **role_2** I want the process definition to be instantiated only by users of **role_1**. If it's possible what do I have to do to?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be assigned a specific user or role/group as potential initiator of a process using the attributes namely **`<`activiti:candidateStarterUsers`>`** and **`<`activiti:candidateStarterGroups`>`**.

example:

`<process id="myProcess" activiti:candidateStarterUsers="kermit, isuru" activiti:candidateStarterGroups="role1">`

On the other hand a user or group can be assigned as potential initiator of a process using **`<`activiti:potentialStarter`>`** tag.

example:

```
<process id="myProcess">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:potentialStarter>
       <resourceAssignmentExpression>
         <formalExpression>group(role1), user(kermit)</formalExpression>
        </resourceAssignmentExpression>
    </activiti:potentialStarter>
</extensionElements>
```

Comment: Small update this is not working on activiti 5.23(the last version of activiti 5). Parsing of xml after model is deployed to activiti-explorer just drops 'activiti:candidateStarterUsers', 'activiti:candidateStarterGroups' or 'activiti:potentialStarter'.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the CandidateStarterGroup property on the Process definition for this.
Refer to chapter 8.8 in the Users guide :

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#security

Hope this helps.